# Retrofit 2 - how to set dynamic cache time to different endpoint

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to set different cache time to different endpoints, what are the best practices for that?

This is my Retrofit interface:

```
public interface ServerApi {

@GET("a1")// need to get 10 mintuns cache time
Observable<A1> getA1();

@GET("a2")// need to get 20 mintuns cache time
Observable<A2> getA2();

@GET("a3")// need to get 30 mintuns cache time
Observable<A3> getA3();
```

This is my network class:

```
public class Network {
Network() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    retrofit.create(ServerApi.class);
}}
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @aleksandrbel check the answer from Andrej Jurkin, is works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server provides correct cache-control headers. OkHttp will handle the caching for you.

Init cache for your Retrofit client

```
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
Cache cache = new Cache(app.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
```

Build OkHttp client, provide cache

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            // Add cache
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
```

Build Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
                    .createWithScheduler(Schedulers.newThread()))
            // Add OkHttp client
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

If for some reason your server does not provide cache-headers. You can always hardcode request interceptors and add cache-headers on the client side.

You could probably use some combination of these:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>
Cache-Control: max-stale[=<seconds>]
```

But if you decide to do that, ask a simple question. What if I decide to change expiry times? You'd probably end up writing some unnecessary code or ship a new APK version. Not cool.

Good luck.

Comment: is not my server so i don't have control on cache-control.

to do it hardcode i need to write it on the interface? 
with annotations headers?     @Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=640000")

Comment: Well, it depends. You can send a cache-control header in request in order to request specific caching behavior, but you need to test it yourself and see if the server responds with cache-control headers. If not, you need to write response interceptor, to intercept responses and attach correct headers.